# Heteromino: Solitude

Tags: grid-deduction

**Heteromino** is an area-dividing puzzle with very simple rules.

Here is an example puzzle with solution:

[image] [image]

The rules of Heteromino are as follows:

1. Divide the white area into L- or I-trominoes.
2. No two trominoes of identical shape and orientation may share an edge.

Now, solve the following puzzle. This time, I tried to come up with a puzzle that has all walls isolated (in terms of four-way neighborhood).

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some thought will show that this line is impossible:

> The gray line at the bottom is impossible, because it will break the bottom left corner.
>  [image]
>
>  And then this one is as well, because it causes a contradiction in the region just above it. (We must have that ⅃ region because otherwise it would cut off the wrong number of cells in the lower left corner.)
>  [image]

That gets us this far:

> [image]
>  We *must* have this line marked in pink. Otherwise, we'd have the wrong number of cells in the lower right corner, and we'd be forced to make a region of 2 or 4.
>  This resolves the bottom right corner:
>  [image]
>  and near the top, the same argument applies two more times to get the two dashes marked above.

We can now start to finish off some more regions:

> This gray-marked region is bad, because it causes a problem immediately below it.
>  [image]
>
>  This lets us finish off the middle region...
>  [image]
>
>  The top-left corner must go down at least once. If it goes down twice, we have two L shapes touching along the left wall.
>
>  So this lets us finish off that corner...
>  [image]
>  And finally, in the top right corner, we can't have this wall or it breaks the upper left of its region:
>  [image]
>  and placing a region like this also causes a problem:
>  [image]

...so we get the final answer:

> [image]

Comment: Excellent. I used small case splits with backtracking, and your logic looks much more elegant. Btw, I thought "is there something wrong with my puzzle?" when I read the first line...

Comment: @Bubbler Yep, Heteromino is a surprisingly difficult genre! I haven't (successfully) done too many of them before, but I know that the logic can be trickier than you might expect. This was a nice puzzle though!